# Making a fully connected graph using a distance metric

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Say I have a series of several thousand nodes. For each pair of nodes I have a distance metric. This distance metric could be a physical distance ( say x,y coordinates for every node ) or other things that make nodes similar.

Each node can connect to up to N other nodes, where N is small - say 6.

How can I construct a graph that is fully connected ( e.g. I can travel between any two nodes following graph edges ) while minimizing the total distance between all graph nodes.

That is I don't want a graph where the total distance for any traversal is minimized, but where for any node the total distance of all the links from that node is minimized.

I don't need an absolute minimum - as I think that is likely NP complete - but a relatively efficient method of getting a graph that is close to the true absolute minimum.

Comment: I'm not sure, but what about a modified MST? I think the fault will be tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a greedy heuristic where you select edges until all vertices have 6 neighbors. For example, start with a minimum spanning tree. Then, for some random pairs of vertices, find a shortest path between them that uses at most one of the unselected edges (using Dijkstra's algorithm on two copies of the graph with the selected edges, connected by the unselected edges). Then select the edge that yielded in total the largest decrease of distance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a kernel to create edges only for nodes under a certain cutoff distance.

- If you want **non-weighted edges** You could simply use a basic cutoff to start with. You add an edge between 2 points if d(v1,v2) < R

  You can tweak your cutoff R to get the right average number of edges between nodes.
- If you want a **weighted graph**, the preferred kernel is often the gaussian one, with

  K(x,y) = e^(-d(x,y)^2/d_0)

  with a cutoff to keep away nodes with too low values. d_0 is the parameter to tweak to get the weights that suits you best.

While looking for references, I found this blog post that I didn't about, but that seems very explanatory, with many more details : http://charlesmartin14.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/spectral-clustering/

This method is used in graph-based semi-supervised machine learning tasks, for instance in image recognition, where you tag a small part of an object, and have an efficient label propagation to identify the whole object.

You can search on google for : *semi supervised learning with graph*